# Can anyone explain this custom react hook function to me?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I saw this react form custom hook in a Youtube video and the return statement confuses me. I see that we are returning an array, and I understand using the spread operator but I don't understand why we are doing `[e.target.name]:e.target.value` especially using square brackets on e.target.name. Can anyone explain? What is this called in Javascript?

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export const useForm = (initalValues) => {
    const [values, setValues] = useState(initalValues);

    return [
        values,
        (e) => {
            setValues({
                ...values,
                [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
            });
        },
    ];
};
```

Comment: That's a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015). So if e.target.name is "bob", then it's creating an the object `{...values, bob: "bob" }`

Comment: You should link the Youtube video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's used when the property name is computed at runtime. Since you don't know the name of the key in advance, you use this. When this code runs, `[e.target.value]` will be the `name` of the input field.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of that custom hook is to wrap the state dispatch (`setValues`) around a function to handle an event, most likely front an input field. So I imagine the end result would look something like this:

```
import useForm from "./useForm"

const FunctionalComponent = () => {
  const [value, handleEvent] = useForm({
    name1: "",
    name2: "" 
  });

  return (
    <input name="name1" value={value} onChange={handleEvent} />
    <input name="name2" value={value} onChange={handleEvent} />
  );
}
```

The way the hook is using those square brackets helps it select the name property inside the event object.